# how to install live Ubuntu dvd to permanent install

Tags: livedvd

I have a live Ubuntu dvd when I insert rhe dvd it automatically installed without giving any opinions. 
And its language also changed. 
Please help me how to get install permanent and how to change language. 
Thanks

Comment: take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

The Live OS that boots is not really installed unless you choose to install it with the 'Install Ubuntu' option on the screen. Till then you may try it out to see if it fits you fine.